# How to get value for the missing months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample Table :

```
Month     Id1 Id2 Id3  value1  value2 
Dec-17     1   1   1     10     10
Jan-18     1   1   1     null   null
Feb-18     1   1   1     20     10
Mar-18     1   1   1     20     10
Apr-18     1   1   1     10     30
Jan-18     2   2   2     10     20
Mar-18     2   2   2     10     10
```

The composite key for my table is month+Id1+Id2+Id3 .
Depending on the month of the quarter ,I want to apply some logic .
For eg .for each month of the quarter ,the output should be sum of previous months and sum of current and future months

I wanted to use lag and lead function and I am using partition over (Id1,Id2,Id3) ,So I don't want null neither I want 0 in Id1,Id2,Id3 .I considered using left outer join to fetch all months ,but that would populate null or 0 in Id1,Id2,Id3 .

I wanted to use lag and lead as depending on the month ,I need to consider the next and previous months in the logic
Can someone please help

Comment: COALESCE() perhaps?

Comment: COALESCE() will ultimately give null in ID1,Id2,Id3

Comment: Even if you add a 0 as last item?

Comment: The value for May is 10 anyway, so why are the missing months relevant? And why are you *only* showing output for May? It isn't clear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi Alex ,Modified the question ,Please have a look

Comment: @joe - so you want each month to show the total value for the quarter it is in? If the missing months are zero then they still aren't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to show the total of the values for the quarter the month is in. You can use an analytic `sum()` rather than `lag()`:

```
sum(value) over (partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q'))
```

Demo, getting the sample data via a CTE, and also including the valut of the quarter-to-date for fun::

```
with your_table(Month, Id1, Id2, Id3, value) as (
            select date '2017-12-01', 1, 1, 1, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-02-01', 1, 1, 1, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 1, 1, 1, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-09-01', 1, 1, 1, 20 from dual
)
select to_char(month, 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as month,
  id1, id2, id3, value,
  sum(value) over (partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')) as qtr,
  sum(value) over (partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month) as qtd
from your_table;

MONTH         ID1        ID2        ID3      VALUE        QTR        QTD
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Dec-17          1          1          1         10         10         10
Feb-18          1          1          1         10         10         10
Apr-18          1          1          1         10         20         10
May-18          1          1          1         10         20         20
Sep-18          1          1          1         20         20         20
```

Missing months don't exist so don't affect the sum. (You would have an issue if months were there but had value set to null rather than zero; but then you could just coalesce those).

Based on your latest update you have *two* values; you want to use `value1` for any previous months in the quarter, and `value2` for the current month and any future months in the quarter.

You can get those with suitable window clauses; again using a CTE for you new sample data:

```
with your_table(month, id1, id2, id3, value1, value2) as (
            select date '2017-12-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-02-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 30 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-09-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
)
select to_char(month, 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as month,
  id1, id2, id3, value1, value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0) as qbd_value1,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qfd_value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0)
  +
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qtr_value
from your_table;
```

which gets:

```
MONTH  ID1 ID2 ID3 VALUE1 VALUE2 QBD_VALUE1 QFD_VALUE2  QTR_VALUE
------ --- --- --- ------ ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
Dec-17   1   1   1     10     10          0         10         10
Jan-18   1   1   1                        0         20         20
Feb-18   1   1   1     10     10          0         20         20
Mar-18   1   1   1     20     10         10         10         20
Apr-18   1   1   1     10     30          0         40         40
May-18   1   1   1     10     10         10         10         20
Sep-18   1   1   1     20     10          0         10         10
```

You don't need to select the quarter-before-date sum of `value1` (`qbd_value1`) or the quarter-from-date sum of `value2` (`qfd_value2`) values separately, I've just included them so you can see/check them; the relevant part is when they are added together to generate `qtr_value`.

So:

- for Jan it gives you Jan value2 (null->0) + Feb value2 (10) + Mar value2 (10) => 20.
- for Feb it gives you Jan value1 (null->0) + Feb value2 (10) + Mar value2 (10) => 20.
- for Mar it gives you Jan value1 (null->0) + Feb value1 (10) + Mar value1 (10) => 20.

Not the most helpful sample data...

- for Apr it gives you Apr value2 (30) + May value2 (10) => 40. (no data for Jun)
- for May it gives you Apr value1 (10) + May value2 (10) => 20.

---

With your latest sample data:

```
with your_table(month, id1, id2, id3, value1, value2) as (
            select date '2017-12-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-02-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 30 from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 20 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 10 from dual
)
...
```

the same query gets:

```
MONTH  ID1 ID2 ID3 VALUE1 VALUE2 QBD_VALUE1 QFD_VALUE2  QTR_VALUE
------ --- --- --- ------ ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
Dec-17   1   1   1     10     10          0         10         10
Jan-18   1   1   1                        0         20         20
Feb-18   1   1   1     20     10          0         20         20
Mar-18   1   1   1     20     10         20         10         30
Apr-18   1   1   1     10     30          0         30         30
Jan-18   2   2   2     10     20          0         30         30
Mar-18   2   2   2     10     10         10         10         20
```

which seems to match your expectations.

---

Going away from your original question but looking at the unusual quarters, you can see the months being used by adding analytic min and max (though those are confusing if there are missing months still, so I've re-added May with null values to make it slightly clearer):

```
with your_table(month, id1, id2, id3, value1, value2) as (
            select date '2017-12-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-02-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 30 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 20 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 10 from dual
)
select to_char(month, 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as month,
  id1, id2, id3, value1, value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0) as qbd_value1,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qfd_value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0)
  +
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qtr_value,
  to_char(min(month) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ), 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as qtr_start,
  to_char(max(month) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(month, 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as qtr_end
from your_table;

MONTH  ID1 ID2 ID3 VALUE1 VALUE2 QBD_VALUE1 QFD_VALUE2  QTR_VALUE QTR_START       QTR_END        
------ --- --- --- ------ ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
Dec-17   1   1   1     10     10          0         10         10 Dec-17          Dec-17         
Jan-18   1   1   1                        0         20         20 Jan-18          Mar-18         
Feb-18   1   1   1     20     10          0         20         20 Jan-18          Mar-18         
Mar-18   1   1   1     20     10         20         10         30 Jan-18          Mar-18         
Apr-18   1   1   1     10     30          0         30         30 Apr-18          May-18         
May-18   1   1   1                       10          0         10 Apr-18          May-18         
Jan-18   2   2   2     10     20          0         30         30 Jan-18          Mar-18         
Mar-18   2   2   2     10     10         10         10         20 Jan-18          Mar-18
```

TO get your adjusted ranges you can use `add_months()` inside the `trunc()` call, as mentioned in comments, inside all the analytic clauses:

```
with your_table(month, id1, id2, id3, value1, value2) as (
            select date '2017-12-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-02-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 1, 1, 1, 20, 10 from dual
  union all select date '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1, 10, 30 from dual
  union all select date '2018-05-01', 1, 1, 1, null, null from dual
  union all select date '2018-01-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 20 from dual
  union all select date '2018-03-01', 2, 2, 2, 10, 10 from dual
)
select to_char(month, 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as month,
  id1, id2, id3, value1, value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0) as qbd_value1,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qfd_value2,
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value1, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0)
  +
  coalesce(sum(coalesce(value2, 0)) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 0) as qtr_value,
  to_char(min(month) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ), 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as qtr_start,
  to_char(max(month) over (
    partition by id1, id2, id3, trunc(add_months(month, 1), 'Q')
    order by month
    rows between current row and unbounded following
  ), 'Mon-RR', 'nls_date_language=english') as qtr_end
from your_table;

MONTH  ID1 ID2 ID3 VALUE1 VALUE2 QBD_VALUE1 QFD_VALUE2  QTR_VALUE QTR_START       QTR_END        
------ --- --- --- ------ ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
Dec-17   1   1   1     10     10          0         20         20 Dec-17          Feb-18         
Jan-18   1   1   1                       10         10         20 Dec-17          Feb-18         
Feb-18   1   1   1     20     10         10         10         20 Dec-17          Feb-18         
Mar-18   1   1   1     20     10          0         40         40 Mar-18          May-18         
Apr-18   1   1   1     10     30         20         30         50 Mar-18          May-18         
May-18   1   1   1                       30          0         30 Mar-18          May-18         
Jan-18   2   2   2     10     20          0         20         20 Jan-18          Jan-18         
Mar-18   2   2   2     10     10          0         10         10 Mar-18          Mar-18
```

Comment: Hi Alex , I have yet again modified the question , depending on the months of the quarter , I need to add previous and next months , so I was using lag and lead

Comment: @joe - it would have been much easier if you'd explained what you were actually doing to begin with. It would also be helpful to show the expected results for all the sample data (and perhaps not have so many things with the same values, to make it less confusing). The bits of expected reulsts you have now are confusing and I think contradictory.

Comment: Hi Alex !!! Thanks for the answer .I was not aware of preceding in sql .Seems like with this ,I dont need to  worry about the missing months ,also this is a better alternative than lead ,lag.

Comment: How do I partition the months ,for different calendar , for eg . trunc('May-18','Q') returns Apr-18 , But what if my quarter starts from June

Comment: @joe - simplest way is probably `trunc(add_months(month, -1), 'Q')`. Or possibly +2, not sure which way you mean, try both and see which is right for you *8-)

Comment: Hi Alex ..I asked new question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085347/how-to-partition-over-months-and-group-months-in-a-quarter.  Please have a look

Comment: You seem to have swapped the order of the trunc and add-months in that, not sure why. Gordon seems to be dealing with it though.

Comment: @joe - i you want Dec-Feb, Mar-May and Jun-Aug then the `add_months()` second argument is either -2 or +1... I've added a version using +1. (Which is what mathguy is doing  too; but you don't need the second `add-months(..., -1)` call here as you aren't displaying it.)

Comment: Hi Alex ,how do I include the months ,that are not there in the input table ?

Comment: @joe - using [a partitioned outer join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-01B5DD6F-C039-4223-B017-263F7788C4FA) would work here. Or [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17818363/266304), which is similar but not partitioned. If you can't get ti working then you'll need to ask a new question; but this sort of thing has been asked many times before.

Comment: Thanks Alex !! Let me check the questions you mentioned .

Comment: Hi Alex .. so the partitioned outer join takes care of the other columns , that is unlike left outer join it does not make the other columns as null .By other column I mean ,columns which are not included in join .Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
a.d month,nvl(id1,0) id1,nvl(id2,0) id2,nvl(id3,0) id3,nvl(value,0)value
from 
    ( SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2018-01-01',(level-1)),'Mon-YY') d
FROM  DUAL
CONNECT BY level < 13) a left join mytable
     on a.d=mytable.month
```

if any doubts -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b8c7/14

Comment: Hi ksl123 ,I have edited my question ,Please have a look.Thanks anyways for the reply

Comment: how is the month column stored?

Comment: Hi Ksl123 ,I have formatted the month as '01-May-18'