# How to partition over months and group months in a quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to apply partition over on some months columns and group them in a quarter.

```
Months

Jan-18
Feb-18
Mar-18
Apr-18
May-18
Jun-18
Jul-18
Aug-18
Sep-18
Oct-18
Nov-18
Dec-18
```

My calendar starts from Jun

So

```
Jun,Jul,Aug is considered as 1st quarter .
Sep,Oct,Nov is considered as 2nd quarter .
Dec,Jan,Feb is considered as 3rd quarter .
Mar,Apr,May is considered as 4th quarter .

trunc(Jan-18,'q')returns 01-Jan-18

whereas expected result is '01-Nov-18' .
```

I tried

```
select ADD_MONTHS(trunc(to_date('01-APR-18'), 'Q'),2) from dual;
```

also tried

```
select ADD_MONTHS(trunc(to_date('01-JUN-18'), 'Q'),-1) from dual;
output is '01-Mar-18',whereas expected reuslt is '01-JUN-18' .
```

expected Result set :

```
 Months     Expected result 

02-Jan-18      01-Dec-17
02-Feb-18      01-Dec-17
05-Mar-18      01-Mar-18
08-Apr-18      01-Mar-18
05-May-18      01-Mar-18
05-Jun-18      01-Jun-18
05-Jul-18      01-Jun-18
09-Aug-18      01-Jun-18
10-Sep-18      01-Sep-18
11-Oct-18      01-Sep-18
11-Nov-18      01-Sep-18
11-Dec-18      01-Dec-18
```

Can someone please help

Comment: Can you provide the result set you want?  It is not clear what you want to do with the quarters from the question.

Comment: Hi Gordon ,edited the question .Please check

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense (you probably didn't double-check what you wrote). The first day of the quarter that contains Jan-18 should be 01-Dec-17, not 01-Nov-18 (Why 18 anyway, regardless of month?) Please be careful and double and triple check your posts; you are only hurting your credibility if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the solution you tried is that you are missing a step.

If your quarters are off by one month from "standard" quarters, then - given a date, any date - you must move the date forward by one month, **then** truncate to the quarter and then pull back by one month. You did steps 2 and 3 but you are missing step 1.

```
with
  inputs ( dt ) as (
    select to_date('02-Jan-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('02-Feb-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('05-Mar-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('08-Apr-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('05-May-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('05-Jun-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('05-Jul-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('09-Aug-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('10-Sep-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('11-Oct-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('11-Nov-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
    select to_date('11-Dec-18', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual
  )
select dt,
       add_months(trunc(add_months(dt, 1), 'q'), -1) as qtr
from   inputs;

DT          QTR     
---------   ---------
02-Jan-18   01-Dec-17
02-Feb-18   01-Dec-17
05-Mar-18   01-Mar-18
08-Apr-18   01-Mar-18
05-May-18   01-Mar-18
05-Jun-18   01-Jun-18
05-Jul-18   01-Jun-18
09-Aug-18   01-Jun-18
10-Sep-18   01-Sep-18
11-Oct-18   01-Sep-18
11-Nov-18   01-Sep-18
11-Dec-18   01-Dec-18
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `case`?

```
select (case when extract(month from <date>) in (6, 7, 8) then 1
             when extract(month from <date>) in (9, 10, 11) then 2
             when extract(month from <date>) in (12 1, 2) then 3
             when extract(month from <date>) in (3, 4, 5) then 4
        end) as quarter
```

You can use the built-in functions with something like this to get the quarter:

```
select to_char(add_months(<date>, -5), 'Q')
```

This will also work with `trunc()`:

```
select trunc(add_months(<date>, -5), 'Q')
```

If what you want is the start date, you can use the `case` (which is the most explicit and easy to follow) or do fancy arithmetic:

```
select add_months(add_months(trunc(add_months(<date>, -5), 'YYYY'), 6),
                  to_number(to_char(add_months(<date>, -5), 'Q')) * 3 - 4
                 )
```

This adds the number of quarters since the first of June for what should be the fiscal year you are in.

Here is a little [rextester](http://rextester.com/KWYCK90609) for it.

Comment: Hi Gordon .Thanks for the reply . I dont want quarter number i.e Jun ,Jul,Aug would be 1 ,Sep,Oct,Nov would be 2 . I want to apply partition over the months.So I am expecting Jun-18,Jul-18Aug-18 to return 01-Jun-18

Comment: @joe . . . The final query should do what you want.

Comment: @Gordon..I have provided expected result set in the question

Comment: The OP needs an actual date. The quarter identified by the start date 1-Dec-2017 is not the same as the quarter identified by the start date 1-Dec-2018.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The last query provides the quarter start date.

Comment: What output will that last query give for an input date in 2016, or in 2019? I don't see how adding to a hard-coded date in 2018 will work for all inputs.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Duh!  I get it now.  Thank you.